# android addmarker redirct to wrong position

Tags: android, camera, location, geocoder

If I paste the output of log lat and log long in google maps it redirects to correct location but `animateCamera()` is redirecting to wrong place in google maps android app. please help!

```
 public void onSearch(View view){
            Log.i("******************","in search function");
            EditText locationTf = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
            String location = locationTf.getText().toString();
            Log.i("Entered location:",location);
            if(location != null || location.equals("")){
                Log.i("In if statement","all condition are satisfied");
                Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this);
                try {
                    addresses = geocoder.getFromLocationName(location,1);
                    Log.i("in try block",addresses.toString());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                Address address = addresses.get(0);
                Log.i("after try catch block",address.toString());
                LatLng searchLatLng = new LatLng(address.getLatitude(),address.getLatitude());
                double logLat = address.getLatitude() ;
                double logLon = address.getLongitude() ;
                Log.i("********************","&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&");
                Log.i(Double.toString(logLat),Double.toString(logLon));

                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(searchLatLng).title("Results"));
                mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(searchLatLng));
               // mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(searchLatLng, 10));
            }
            else {

            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're passing 2 lattitudes.

```
LatLng(address.getLatitude(),address.getLatitude());
```

Instead of

```
LatLng(address.getLatitude(),address.getLongitude());
```